# Is it possible to get a proxy-IP during the current scraping iteration when scraping using the methods of the requests library?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm making a scraping script for a `SPA` site using `selenium` to pull out certain dynamic values. When creating the browser object, I replace proxy-IP instead my real IP. And before I put the script to work for several hours, I need to make sure that the site perceives exactly the `proxy-IP`, not real.

But I can't figure out where to get it from? And is there such information in the `response` object?

```
import requests as rq

response = rq.get(url)
```

I read all the documentation on `requests` (maybe, of course, I missed something), printed almost all the methods that, presumably, may contain such information, but did not find anything.

I can, of course, indirectly verify the effectiveness of the scraper script by testing the script on any `IP` determination site by getting data from a specific `div`. But suddenly it will work on such a site, but on the target site that needs to be scraped, there is some kind of tricky protection and it will not work (could it be?).

I will be grateful for any answer!

**P.S.:** I'm not a native English speaker, so I can't always correctly translate my native technical language into technical English. Therefore, if something is not clear to you in my question, I ask you to show tolerance and professional ethics - do not dislike or close the question, but clarify what details I missed.

Comment: There is nothing the target site could do to "unmask" your IP behind a proxy. If your server and the proxy you're going through are correctly configured so your request _actually_ goes out through the proxy, and the proxy is an opaque proxy which does not reveal your IP in a "Forwarded-For" HTTP header or such, then the target site _will_ only see the proxy's IP address and has no way to get your IP behind it.

Answer (score 0):

For validating the proxy-ip, you can use [www.httbin.org](https://httpbin.org/ip)

Example script:

```py
import requests as rq

proxies = {
   'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080',
   'https': 'http://secureproxy.example.com:8090',
}

response = rq.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies)
ip = response.json()["origin"]

print(ip)
```

[resource](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/python-requests-proxy/)